# Graph Explorer | Graph API | Sites Search | Item not found

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, graph-explorer

Below query is returning "item not found" but the user executing the query actually has access to SharePoint sites as well as is Admin of one of the SharePoint site.

Is there any specific permission required for this query to bring results?

[image: Graph API Issue - item not found]

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to `Modify permissions` tab in Graph Explorer, you will see all permissions required for the current endpoint.

The endpoint `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*` requires `Sites.Readl.All` or `Sites.ReadWrite.All` permissions.

[image]